# Pass createReadStream within GraphQL mutation (jest test purposes)

Tags: javascript, jestjs, graphql

I'm struggling to pass createReadStream within a mutation query.

What I do is mocking with Jest as below

```js
const createReadStream = jest.fn();
```

and I'm using it like this

```js
file: {
  filename: "Marvel (1).pdf",
  mimetype: "application/pdf",
  encoding: "7bit",
  createReadSteam: ${createReadStream}
}
```

here is the entire code

```js
import { initResources } from 'jeto';
import { graphql } from 'graphql';
import { prop, path } from 'ramda';
import initServices from '../services';
import initHttp from '../init/http';
import initModels from '../init/models';
import initConfig from './initConfig';
import initDatabase from '../init/database';
import initRouter from '../init/router';
import initDataLoaders from '../dataLoaders';
import initApollo from '../init/apollo';
import api from '../../lib/api';
import { ROLE } from '../../lib/models/people';
import { login } from './utils';
// import { resumes } from './utils/resumesTests';
// import { userAdmin, userHeadHunter, userSales, userWorker } from './utils/usersTests';

let MONGO;
let SERVER;
let runql;
let CTX;
let GCTX;
let PROFILE;
const TENANT = { key: 'TENANT' };

describe('server | graphql | Resumes', () => {
  beforeAll(async () => {
    const resources = [
      initConfig,
      initDatabase,
      initModels,
      initDataLoaders,
      initServices,
      initApollo,
      initRouter,
      initHttp,
    ];

    return initResources(resources)
      .then(async ctx => {
        CTX = ctx;
        const { httpServer, mongo, models } = ctx();
        MONGO = mongo;
        SERVER = httpServer;
        const tenantId = await models.tenants.collection.insertOne(TENANT).then(prop('insertedId'));
        TENANT._id = tenantId;
        api.config({ endpoint: httpServer.url, tenant: TENANT.key });
        const { user } = await login(models, TENANT, [ROLE.admin]);
        GCTX = {
          user,
          ctx: CTX,
          models: CTX().models(user, { authRequired: true, ...TENANT }),
          dataLoaders: CTX().dataLoaders,
        };
        runql = async query => {
          console.log('query', query);

          const res = await graphql(CTX().apollo.schema, query, null, GCTX);
          console.log('res', res);

          if (res.errors) throw res.errors[0];
          return res;
        };
      })
      .catch(() => {
        if (MONGO) {
          MONGO.database.dropDatabase();
          MONGO.close();
        }
      });
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    return MONGO.database
      .dropDatabase()
      .then(() => SERVER.close())
      .then(() => MONGO.close());
  });

  it('should add resumes', async () => {
    const createReadStream = jest.fn();
    const query = `
    mutation {
        createResume(
            status: checking,
            firstname: "Mathieu",
            lastname: "Chedid",
            email: "mchedid@gmail.com",
            phoneNumber: "+33 9 49 48 50 54",
            rating: 5,
            seniority: 6,
            hardSkills: ["6048d850735ec00ec36db0d9", "6048d850735ec00ec36db0c4", "6048d850735ec00ec36db0b8"],
            softSkills: [],
            comment: "",
            file: {
                filename: "Marvel (1).pdf",
                mimetype: "application/pdf",
                encoding: "7bit",
                createReadSteam: ${createReadStream}
            }
        ){ _id } }`;

    PROFILE = await runql(query).then(path(['data', 'createResume']));

    expect(PROFILE._id).toBeDefined();
  });
```

The console log

```sh
GraphQLError [Object]: Syntax Error: Expected Name, found "(".
```

When I get rid of

```js
  createReadSteam: ${createReadStream}
```

from file and start over the test, I can observe this within the console

```
Error: ‘Upload’ scalar literal unsupported.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned @xadm, the solution was to add the uploaded file aside the query, and modify runql method to add an argument -> variables

```js
it('should add a resume', async () => {
    const stream = Readable.from(Buffer.from('coucou'));
    const query = `
      mutation 
        createResume($file: Upload)
          { 
            createResume(
                file: $file,
                firstname: "mathieu",
                lastname: "chedid",
                email: "mchedid@gmail.com",
                phoneNumber: "+33 6 17 82 54 08"
                status: pending,
                seniority: 1,
                hardSkills: ["6048d850735ec00ec36db0d9"] 
            ) { _id, firstname } 
          } 
    `;
    const file = Promise.resolve({
      createReadStream: () => stream,
      stream,
      filename: './resume.pdf',
      mimetype: `application/pdf`,
    });
    RESUME = await runql(query, { file }).then(path(['data', 'createResume']));
    expect(RESUME._id).toBeDefined();
    expect(RESUME.firstname).toEqual('mathieu');
  });
```

```js
runql = async (query, variables = {}) => {
    const res = await graphql(CTX().apollo.schema, query, null, GCTX, variables);
    if (res.errors) throw res.errors[0];
    return res;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st: mutation arguments should be always passed as variables** https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables -

### There is literally no possibility to pass files/uploads hardcoded inside the query!

**2nd: graphQL uploads are usually implemented as 2 step process described in [specs](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec)** :

- **preprocessing** - request is made using classic **POST multipart form-data** encoded dataset with `operations` (contains graphql `"query"` and args processed later - mutation plus `"variables"` - **non-file and nulled files args**), `map` (files to query variables mapping) and files
- query(mutation) passed to normal processing gets **updated `"variables"`, file variables are `Upload` scalars now** (depends on implementation) - object with name, uploaded file/stream handle.

For 2nd step testing follow 'normal' **node.js [upload] file/stream mocking**.

Already answered solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57577873/6124657)